# R & PortfolioAnalytics: Error on create.EfficientFrontier

Tags: r, finance

I am working on the Efficient Frontier on R with `PortfolioAnalytics` package.
However I have encountered this error on `create.EfficientFrontier` even using the demo codes:

> Error in seq.default(from = minret, to = maxret, length.out = n.portfolios) : 
>     'from' must be a finite number`

**Demo code used:**

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(DEoptim)
library(ROI)
require(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
require(ROI.plugin.glpk)

data(edhec)
R <- edhec[, 1:5]
# change the column names for better legends in plotting
colnames(R) <- c("CA", "CTAG", "DS", "EM", "EQM")
funds <- colnames(R)

# initial portfolio object
init <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)
# initial constraints
init <- add.constraint(portfolio=init, type="full_investment")
init <- add.constraint(portfolio=init, type="box", min=0.15, max=0.45)
init <- add.constraint(portfolio=init, type="group",
                       groups=list(c(1, 3),
                                   c(2, 4, 5)),
                       group_min=0.05,
                       group_max=0.7)

# create mean-etl portfolio
meanetl.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init, type="risk", name="ES")
meanetl.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=meanetl.portf, type="return", name="mean")

# create mean-var portfolio
meanvar.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init, type="risk", name="var", risk_aversion=10)
meanvar.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=meanvar.portf, type="return", name="mean")

# create efficient frontiers

# mean-var efficient frontier
meanvar.ef <- create.EfficientFrontier(R=R, portfolio=init, type="mean-StdDev")
```

This error appears today. I have this error on other codes which I ran smoothly before. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue. It happens with shorter return series, i.e. runs ok with returns over 50 date points, but generates the same error with truncated returns, e.g. 36.

Comment: I have been debugging this issue further. It is because the matrix in the input parameters of the quadratic solver is not positive definite. See the 'out' values of the 'ROI_solve' function. There are 3 ways of resolving it: using the DEoptim instead of ROI (very slow); using something like this https://github.com/R-Finance/PortfolioAnalytics/blob/master/sandbox/testing_turnover.gmv.R - with Q=make.positive.definite; and hacking the PortfolioAnalytics code - to add matrix conversion to positive definite.